# unique constraint некорректно срабатывает в sqlite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework

Всем привет. столкнулся с такой проблемой. Разрабатываю программу на WPF. Подключил существующую БД sqlite к проекту. Есть сущность деталь сборки Part (сборка - это файл, конечное изделие, разработанное САПР, состоит из деталей)

```
[Table("Parts")]
public class Part : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Part_id")]
    public int PartId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte [] Image { get; set; }

    [Column("Insert_date")]
    public string InsertDate { get; set; }

    [Index("IDX_INTERNAL_REVISION", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Column("Internal_name")]
    public string InternalName { get; set; }

    [Index("IDX_INTERNAL_REVISION", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    [Column("Revision_id")]
    public string RevisionId { get; set; }

    [Column("Database_revision_id")]
    public string DatabaseRevisionId { get; set; }

    [Column("Model_geometry_version")]
    public string ModelGeometryVersion { get; set; }
}
```

уникальный индекс IDX_INTERNAL_REVISION состоит из 2х полей(`InternalName`, `RevisionId`).
Так же есть сущности свойство детали PartFeature и пересекалка для детали и её свойств Part_PartFeature .

Программа открывает список деталей из сборки, далее деталь можно сохранить в БД. Код, реализующий сохранение:

```
private  void saveAssemblyPartInDB(PartViewModel part, string description)
{
    stdole.IPictureDisp disp = part.PartDocument.Thumbnail;
    try
    {
        byte[] ar = BitmapSource_2_ByteArray(IPictureDisp_2_BitmapSource(disp));
        Part newPart = new Part(part.PartDocument.DisplayName,
                                DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                                part.PartDocument.InternalName,
                                part.PartDocument.RevisionId,
                                part.PartDocument.DatabaseRevisionId,
                                part.PartDocument.ComponentDefinition.ModelGeometryVersion,
                                ar,
                                description);

        List<Part_PartFeature> part_PartFeatures = new List<Part_PartFeature>();
        for (int i = 0; i < part.Properties.Count; i++)
        {
            string key = part.Properties.ElementAt(i).Key;
            assemblyAnalyzer.models.PartFeature partFeature =  db.PartFeatures.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == key);
            if (partFeature == null)
            {
                partFeature = db.PartFeatures.Add(new assemblyAnalyzer.models.PartFeature(part.Properties.ElementAt(i).Key));
            }
            Part_PartFeature part_PartFeature = new Part_PartFeature();
            part_PartFeature.PartFeature = partFeature;
            part_PartFeature.Part = newPart;
            part_PartFeature.FeatureValue = part.Properties.ElementAt(i).Value;
            part_PartFeatures.Add(part_PartFeature);
        }
        db.Parts.Add(newPart);
        db.Part_partfeatures.AddRange(part_PartFeatures);
        db.SaveChanges();
        part.IsSaved = true;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        Part findedPart =  db.Parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.InternalName == part.PartDocument.InternalName && p.RevisionId == part.PartDocument.RevisionId);
        if (findedPart != null)
            FileDialogService.ShowMessage($"Данная деталь уже сохранена под именем \"{findedPart.Name}\", с описанием\n\"{findedPart.Description}\".");
        else
            FileDialogService.ShowMessage($"{ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message}\nОшибка при сохранении детали. Деталь не сохранена.");
        part.IsSaved = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        FileDialogService.ShowMessage($"Неизвестная ошибка при сохранении в детали.");
        part.IsSaved = false;
    }

}
```

Обнаружил следующую проблему:

1. открываю определенный файл сборки, сохраняю оттуда деталь в БД.
2. открываю этот файл еще раз, пытаюсь сохранить туже деталь в БД, падает 1е исключение `DBUpdateException`, что деталь уже есть в БД.
3. после пытаюсь сохранить другую деталь, которой нет в БД. Падает 2е исключение `DBUpdateException`, но детали нет в бд. `Exceprion.Message` говорит, что нарушен тот самый unique constraint IDX_INTERNAL_REVISION. Хотя нарушен он быть не может, в БД одна единственная запись с другими `InternalName` и `RevisionId`. 
   Из за чего может появляться данное исключение?
   Возможно я неправильно обрабатываю 1е исключение `DBUpdateException` и оно затем срабатывает во 2й раз?

Comment: Неудачный дизайн БД, все дело в `уникальный индекс IDX_INTERNAL_REVISION состоит из 2х полей(InternalName, RevisionId).` таких индексов следует избегать.

Comment: @Bulson и из-за этого возникает данная ошибка??

Comment: один id идентифицирует деталь, второй версию детали. оба получаю через API

Comment: _после пытаюсь сохранить другую деталь_ - в этом же сеансе работы? Предыдущая деталь (которая дубликат) была удалена из контекста?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov что значит удалена из контекста?

Comment: `db.Parts.Add(newPart);` - вот деталь добавлена. Если было выброшено исключение, что она дубликат - её нужно удалить (`Remove`)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, ошибка была в этом. Можете объяснить, почему в db.Parts запись не добавляется, а в коллекцию DBParts = db.Parts.Local.ToBindingList() добавляется, хотя напрямую в нее я не добавляю?